# how to print exception and params together using btrace?

Tags: java, btrace

I am trying to print the exception and params in my method. But I can`t get any result from my code.

```
import com.sun.btrace.annotations.*;
import static com.sun.btrace.BTraceUtils.*;

@BTrace
public class HelloWorld {
    @OnMethod(clazz = "com.btrace.test.service.UserServiceImpl"
           , method = "test", location = @Location(Kind.ERROR))
    public static void onThreadStart(Throwable exception, @Self Object self, String param1
        , @Return AnyType result, @Duration long duration) {

        println("UserServiceImpl param1=" + param1);
        Threads.jstack(exception);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not possible in the current version 1.3.10.2

In master the support for this was added recently https://github.com/btraceio/btrace/issues/327

You just need to annotate the `Throwable` argument with `@TargetInstance`